# Assigning variables using body-parser in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm having a problem assigning variables in express.I switched over to using post from get and I'm using *bodyParser* as middleware.

Here's the JSON I get from the browser in node when I execute

> console.log(req.body)

```
{ 'params[chartPID]': '12' }
```

I want to assign the JSON above to a variable.  I've tried using `req.body.params[chartPID]` and many other patterns, but the variable is always undefined.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get the value of **params[chartPID]** ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `console.log(req.body['params[chartPID]'])`

Comment: Thank you for your help.  

The syntax I was looking for is: console.log(req.body["params[chartPID]"]);